# VS2017 Select Start Element

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I opened my project in a folder using file open folder option. It is a web application project(index.html as start page). But I am not able to run the application.

It shows [image]

Where should I define my startup item as this folder-> index.html

Comment: try "Select Startup item..."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify an HTML file under 'Select Startup Item...' as that is still a debug dropdown, and you can't directly debug an HTML file.  See the [Visual Studio 2017 Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) and also the [blog post on the feature in the previews](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/12/open-any-folder-with-visual-studio-15-preview/).

You can launch an HTML file in your default browser using launch.vs.json: right-click the HTML file in Solution Explorer, click Configure Tasks, and create a task similar to the one below, and save.  My page is called 'newpage.html', you'd need to rename for your own page.

```
{
  "taskName": "Show Page",
  "appliesTo": "newpage.html",
  "type": "command",
  "command": "explorer.exe",
  "args": ["newpage.html"]
}
```

Once you've created the task right-click the HTML file again in Solution Explorer and 'Show Page' should be in the menu.  This shows it in the browser.  However it's launched as a file and of course won't let you debug any JavaScript through the Visual Studio IDE.

You can also use more sophisticated third-party task runners such as Gulp or Grunt in Visual Studio folder view to launch pages, using Task Runner Explorer.  In a way the folder view is designed for that: it's intention is to allow you to work on code that hasn't necessarily been developed with Visual Studio which may well use such tools.